# "unknown type name" in c struct while ussing gcc

Tags: c, list, gcc

I have a program which is processing list in c, it  is working perfectly as long as I have it in one source file, when I try to separate it and compile it got this error “ delete_functions.c:15:13: error: unknown type name ‘nodetype’ ” same error goes for functionality_functions.c and insert_functions.c here is the code

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "types.h"
#include "delete_functions.h"
#include "insert_functions.h"
#include "functionality_functions.h"

int main(){
    //i did not upload all the main function code because it is way to long
}
```

types.h

```
typedef char AirportCode[4];
typedef struct nodetype{
    char Airport[4];
    struct nodetype *next;
} nodetype;
```

delete_functions.h

```
void Delete(nodetype *list,char node[4]);
void DeleteLast(nodetype *list);
```

functionality_functions.h

```
void print(nodetype *head);
nodetype *search(nodetype *list,char item[4]);
nodetype *create();
```

insert_functions.h

```
void *InsertLast(nodetype *list,char item[4]);
void *InsertAfter(nodetype *list,char item[4],char node[4]);
```

Comment: You need to include a header in every file that depends on its contents.

Comment: I feel stupid, i thought i don't have to since i had included it before the  "delete_functions.h" "insert_functions.h" "functionality_functions.h" i thought the compiler wouldn't want to "find" it again latter in the code, anyways thanks a lot, you saved me.

Comment: @Ph For future reference: You question includes every file except the ones where the error occurs. In this case the problem was easy to spot, but in other cases it will be 100% impossible to debug without seeing the code...

Comment: With `typedef char AirportCode[4];` why not `AirportCode Airport;` in `struct nodetype`?? You create the `typedef`, but aren't using it?

Comment: @John3136 yes you are right and thanks for mentioning i really didn't know where the problem was and i thought that the part of the code i posted was enough, wrong assumption for sure. I am really new into programing and just got in stactoverflow so I don't know my way around here, but thank you know that I know i will be more specific about my code, and #include the right files

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  typedef char AirportCode[4] helps me a lot latter in the program as john mentioned It was my fault for not posting the whole program, how else could evrybody else know

Comment: No biggie, using `char Airport[4];` is fine -- it was just curious being only 2-lines below the `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the GCC error message, there error is in  the `delete_functions.c` file.

Presumably, it looks like this at the beginning:

```
#include "delete_functions.h"
```

Since `delete_functions.h` does not itself include `types.h`, you need to include it first:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "delete_functions.h"
```

Alternatively, you can add **include guards** to your headers so, that they can safely be included multiple times, like this for `types.h`:

```
#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H

typedef char AirportCode[4];
typedef struct nodetype{
    char Airport[4];
    struct nodetype *next;
} nodetype;

#endif
```

And for `delete_functions.h`:

```
#ifndef DELETE_FUNCTIONS_H
#define DELETE_FUNCTIONS_H

void Delete(nodetype *list,char node[4]);
void DeleteLast(nodetype *list);

#endif
```

The `*_H` include guard macros are necessary because otherwise, `main.c` would not compile anymore: each type in `types.h` can only be defined once per translation unit, and without the guards, every `*.h` would bring in another definition, leading to compiler errors.

Comment: Yes I can see my fault now, that fixed my problem thank you very much!!